# Simplest way to set default values for nested object with undefined values

Tags: javascript, json, undefined

I have a JSON string. I use this to push data to Google Tag Manager via its dataLayer. Example: If page is contact then I'm pushing all the stuff in hitDetails as a nested variable.

```
var dataLayerRepo = {
'/contact': {'hitDetails': {'act': {'type': 'views'}, 'dirObj': {'name': '/contact-us','type': '/page','id': window.location.search+window.location.hash}} }, 
'/': {'hitDetails': {'act': {'type': 'views'}, 'dirObj': {'name': '/homepage','type': '/page','id': window.location.search+window.location.hash,'class': {'lev0': '/booking-process'}}} }, 
};
```

My problem is that for some pages I have fields in hitDetails which don't exist in others (like class and class.lev0). I could just have the fields in the JSON itself with a blank value but I want to keep code bloat down and only push fields that have value.

So I'm using this function to check for the nested levels but it seems messy and cumbersome.

I'm not great at JS, but is there a simpler way to say "whatever nested value you're trying to access in {{hitDetails}} (the variable in GTM), if it doesn't exist just return an empty string".

```
var o = {{hitDetails}};

function checkNested(obj /*, level1, level2, ... levelN*/) {
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments),
      obj = args.shift();
      for (var i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
        if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(args[i])) {
          return false;
        }
        obj = obj[args[i]];
      }
      return true;
}

if (checkNested(o, 'act') == false) { 
    o.act = [];
};

if (checkNested(o, 'act','type') == false) { 
    o.dirObj.act.type = "";
};
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Seems you wanted to try to get the value by variable.
Moreover, the variable come from object with levels.

If I were you, I will check the variable instead of "checkNested()".

Example:

```
function isEmpty(v, defValue) {
    return (typeof (v) == 'undefined') ? defValue : v;
}

if( isEmpty(o.act.type, false) !== false ){
    console.log( 'o.act.type: ' + o.act.type );
}
console.log( 'o.act.keyNotExists: ' + isEmpty(o.act.keyNotExists, 'default value') );
```

Comment: Thanks for that Allen. The code I posted works fine but I have to check for every single level if it exists. It looks like your isEmpty function does the same (I'd have to run the function for all my levels). My question was whether there's an easier/more elegant way of doing it without explicitly referencing the nested levels. Thanks